# While loop in R, need a more efficient code

Tags: r, numerical-methods

I have written an R code to solve the following equations jointly. These are closed-form solutions that require numerical procedure.

[image]

I further divided the numerator and denominator of (B) by N to get arithmetic means.

Here is my code:

```
y=cbind(Sta,Zta,Ste,Zte)           # combine the variables
St=as.matrix(y[,c(1,3)])
Stm=c(mean(St[,1]), mean(St[,2]));   # Arithmetic means of St's
Zt=as.matrix(y[,c(2,4)])
Ztm=c(mean(Zt[,1]), mean(Zt[,2]));    # Arithmetic means of Zt's

theta=c(-20, -20);             # starting values for thetas
tol=c(10^-4, 10^-4);
err=c(0,0);                  
epscon=-0.1                

while (abs(err) > tol | phicon<0) {

### A 
eps = ((mean(y[,2]^2))+mean(y[,4]^2))/(-mean(y[,1]*y[,2])+theta[1]*mean(y[,2])-mean(y[,3]*y[,4])+theta[2]*mean(y[,4]))  
### B 
thetan = Stm + (1/eps)*Ztm              
 
err=thetan-theta
theta=thetan
epscon=1-eps

print(c(ebs,theta))

}
```

Iteration does not stop as the second condition of while loop is not met, the solution is a positive epsilon. I would like to get a negative epsilon. This, I guess requires a grid search or a range of starting values for the Thetas.

Can anyone please help code this process differently and more efficiently? Or help correct my code if there are flaws in it.
Thank you

Comment: I think the condition of your `while` loop should adopt `||` rather than `|`

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding, thanks. Will you please explain why this necessary?

Comment: The shorter form performs elementwise comparisons in much the same way as arithmetic operators. The longer form evaluates left to right examining only the first element of each vector.

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding. What do you think, is the code efficient given the problem? I am getting a positive solution i.e. epsilon>0 which is not consistent with the theory I am looking at.

Comment: I didn't follow the theory so I have no clue if it is efficient....

Comment: I appreciate and I understand that. I don't think you need to read the theory for coding these equations. Epsilon is a production elasticity with respect to factor inputs. I just wanted to see if I could do anything else to improve the actual numerical procedure. I would not want you to read a 10 long background to the problem. Thanks.

Comment: I guess your code is fine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219732/discussion-between-london-and-thomasiscoding).

Comment: "closed-form solutions that require numerical procedure": what ??

Answer (score 2):

If I am right, using linearity your equations have the form

```
ΘA = a + b / ε
ΘB = c + d / ε
1/ε = e ΘA + f ΘB + g
```

This is an easy 3x3 linear system.

Comment: You have to assume a few typos in the equations (Is `Zt1` the same as `ZtA`? and is the final term supposed to be `ZtE` not `ZtA`?), but yeah it just reduces right down. Once you put `1/ε` in the first two it is just a pair of simultaneous equations which you can solve by hand.